# React unexpected token in JSON at position 0 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, express

I am getting the following error:-

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

**code:-**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import { Editor, EditorState, convertFromRaw } from "draft-js";

const PostPage = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { postId } = useParams();

  const [description, setDescription] = useState();

  const { post, isSuccess } = useSelector((state) => state.posts);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getpost(postId));
  }, [dispatch, post]);

  const contentState = convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(post?.description));
  const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="post-details-container">
          <div className="post-details">
            <div className="post-header">
              <div className="post-header-subject-created-at">
                <div className="post-header-subject">{post.subject}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="post-content-container">
              <div className="post-content-header-container">
                <div className="post-content-header">
                  <div className="post-content-username">
                    <div className="post-username">{post.name}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="post-content-description">
                <Editor editorState={editorState} readOnly={true} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PostPage;
```

description is a JSON object which is to be parsed and displayed in the Rich Text Editor's Editor component.

I am getting error because of **post.description** which is a JSON object what could be the reason?

Why is it undefined?

**Edit:-**

when I console.log(post.descritption) I get the following object which is stored in DB as Rich Text.

```
{"blocks":[{"key":"1i9ik","text":"Issue Title","type":"header-three","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}},{"key":"4nluf","text":"Hi,","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}},{"key":"evi0t","text":"","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}},{"key":"5s8vp","text":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[{"offset":0,"length":11,"style":"BOLD"}],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}},{"key":"fkbca","text":"Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, ","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}},{"key":"3dc6a","text":"when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}},{"key":"8rfom","text":"","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}},{"key":"es2ha","text":"one","type":"ordered-list-item","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}},{"key":"aeon1","text":"Two","type":"ordered-list-item","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}},{"key":"ei5sb","text":"Three","type":"ordered-list-item","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}},{"key":"bo9vp","text":"Urgent","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[{"offset":0,"length":6,"style":"BOLD"},{"offset":0,"length":6,"style":"UNDERLINE"}],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}],"entityMap":{}}
```

This object needs to be parsed and then displayed but at the time of parsing I get the error.

Comment: how do you get posts?

Comment: @NikitaMazur using dispatch method for the redux toolkit.

Comment: post.description might be `undefined`, giving you a "u" in position 0.

Comment: @James I have used optional chaining then what could be the reason for it to be still undefined?

Comment: if you fetch the post from some api it might be undefined, when your  page is rendered, also there is an unnecessary dependency "post", in useEffect, which might cause re-renders

Comment: @NikitaMazur when I use the description without JSON parsing it is present but when I parse the description (which has to be parsed can't display JSON object) I am getting the said error.

Comment: Is `post` JSON encoded?  You certainly won't be able to access post.description until you JSON parse post.

Comment: Can you try to debug with 'console.log( )'? Like 'React.useEffect(()=> console.log(post),[post])'. Then, check post's index 0 data. If no error, then 'console.log(convertState)' and so on.

Comment: @James please check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The first render of any data-fetching component like this will return `undefined`, and therefore, your `JSON.parse(post?.description)` is essentially being called as `JSON.parse(undefined)` which will return this error.

You need to do a check for the presence of a value first, something like this:

```
const parsed = post ? convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(post.description)) : undefined
```